# Wnat to send Push notification using APNS via Servicestack apis

Tags: apple-push-notifications, servicestack

I have created an application that uses my apis (created in servicestack). I have .pem file (certificate) and device tokens for sending push notification. Now need to send push notification to the devices. I am very new for APNS and not aware how to use it. Please assist me how to proceed and what I have to put in my api code.
Googled a lot on this topic, some article shows that register the certificate through MMC (Microsoft Management Console) but couldn't find what code need to write api after registering it.